# How can I convert XSD to XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have an XSD schema and I would like to convert it into an XSLT stylesheet that copies the elements represented in the XSD schema.

The reason is because I want to extract only the elements represented in the XSD schema from the XML document that it represents.

Any help or suggestion will be very much appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

An XSD schema only describes the one XML document whilst XSLT transforms one XML document to another so I'm not sure if a converter is the right tool that you would be looking for. Altova (http://www.altova.com/) make some great tools for working with XML.

Comment: Maybe It was not clear enough.. My XSD schema describes only a part of the XML document, so I would like to filter the document using that schema.. My idea is to transform somehow that schema into an XSLT stylesheet so that I can filter the original XML document and obtain a reduced version of it..

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with XSLT. Make a normal XSLT transforming your XML and use the document() function to load your XSD and check if the element is being mentioned in it (and allowed to be copied).

Loading a second XML (in your case a XSD): http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/xslt/document/